# UITextField cursor position change on orientation change

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation, cursor-position

Working fine with iOS6 even if I change the orientation
[image: Working fine with iOS6]

Working fine with iOS7 If I don't change the orientation
[image: Working fine with iOS7]

Error in display when orientation gets change iOS7.*
[image: Error in display when orientation gets change iOS7]

I am creating `UITextField` programmatically, its working fine with < iOS7,

with iOS7 and higher , when I change orientation `UITextField` cursor position gets change. What's the issue? Is it bug of iOS?

The rounded corners `UITextField` you're seeing is `UITextField` only, I just make it rounded by setting corner of `UITextField`.

I've set left and right view of `UITextField`. Also in orientation changes method I'm not even touching that `UITextField`.

Update:

I find that there's contentOffset changes in `UIFieldEditor` subview of `UITextField`

```
- (void)resizeUITextFieldInsideUITextFieldWithOffset:(CGFloat)y {
    for(id subview in [txtSearch subviews]) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            UIScrollView *textField = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            [textField setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y)];
        }
    }
}
```

I fix it using the above code in orientation, but when I type again the same problem occurring again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the uiviwcontroller's  [image] fixed the issue for me, random bug.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that, even after 4 years of asking this question this solution is still working for me :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to resign it when you are going to rotate and again put as first responder as soon as you finish rotating it. I don't actually why it happens but this should make the try.
Do you have autolayout set?